# Want to show two timePickers on one html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

This is my code for one timePicker but i am unable to show two timePickers on one HTML page. The below code is working fine for my one timePicker but i am unable to make Logic that how i should use id's which are different on both inputs .

```
    function redirect(){

  document.getElementById("startTime").value=document.getElementById("test_default").value;

           var stime=document.getElementById("test_default").value;

    //alert(document.getElementById("endTime").value);

              window.localStorage.setItem('starttime', stime);

    //alert(stime);
         window.localStorage.setItem('id', id);
         window.location.replace("block.html");


          }
             function frameURL() {
        /*var address = document.getElementById("startTime");
        //var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
        //var frame = iframe.src;
        //address.value = frame;


             var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
             var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
             var usernameTextBox = innerDoc.getElementById('test_default');

    //usernameTextBox.focus();
            address.value = usernameTextBox;
            alert(usernameTextBox);
    //usernameTextBox.focus();*/

            var thetime= document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById("startTime").value;

              document.getElementById("startTime").value=thetime
         }



            function frameURL2() {


             var thetime=        document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById("startTime").value;

       //alert(thetime);


           document.getElementById("startTime1").value=thetime
         }

          </script>
```

Comment: So no one can help ..:)

Comment: What's the point of all the comments?  Why are you making us read all that code you're not using?  Where is the code for the second time picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use jQuery timePicker. Just add 1 css & 1 Js file and you can use timePicker . This is the timePicker which i have used it's very easy to use. Jquery 1.6.4. Place your both Text Boxes in one div & place the id of that div in this JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >

        $(document).ready(function(){
            // find the input fields and apply the time select to them.
            $('#sample1 input').ptTimeSelect();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: thnx @ PhoneGap Developer i am going to tyr this timePicker now .

Answer (score 0):

I used this: [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) along with jqueryui's Datepicker.

HTML

```
<input class='timePicker' name='time_start'type='text' />
<input class='timePicker' name='time_end'type='text' />
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timePicker').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
    });
});
```